# IB Action is not getting called from Custom View

Tags: ios, swift, view, uibutton, ibaction

I am showing a view when view did appear, there is one button on view which is not getting clicked. Animation is working perfectly fine.

```
func checkNotificationPermission(){

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized{
                    print("ProfileVC permission granted for notification")
                }else{

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {

                        self.productCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 3, options: [.transitionFlipFromTop, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {

                                self.notificationView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 180), width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32), height: 150)

                        }, completion: { (isCompleted) in

                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 10, options: [.transitionFlipFromTop, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {

                                    self.notificationView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32), height: 150)

                            }, completion: { (isCompleted) in
                                self.productCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                            })
                        })
                    }
                    print("ProfileVC permission not granted for notification")
                }
            }
        }else{
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
                print("ProfileVC APNS-YES")
            } else {
                print("ProfileVC APNS-NO")
            }
        }
    }
```

IBAction is there, connection is also there.

```
@IBAction func setttingButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("setting button pressed")
```

}

I checked in view debugger, Custom View is showing top of collection view which you can see under customView.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the func that you connected to the button? Is the breakpoint being hit?

Comment: @waldrumpus I have put simple print statement in IB Action method which is not being executed, I mean can't see anything in console. You can see IB Action code in question now.

Comment: You seem to have tested the view hierarchy properly. But have you tried *insuring* that the button is top-most by using `view.bringSubview(toFront:)`?

Comment: Is `notificationView` a custom class with your button `@IBAction func`? Or is it just a subview of your view controller, and the button pressed func is in the view controller?

Comment: show on which view you are calling this action and how? @GaneshPawar

Answer (score -1):

Check `isUserInteractionEnabled` for the view you have added. It must be `true`

You can debug this property in view debugger itself

Comment: I checked in attribute inspector, `isUserInteractionEnabled` it is checked or set to `true`

Comment: You should check at runtime in `Debug View Hierarchy` mode. If other things are in place, this could be the only reason. You should also provide code VC code storyboard and debug mode screens.

And I didn't understand whats wrong in this answer to downvote.